# Effects of writing clause not visible

Tags: neo4j, cypher

using Neo4j 3.0.4

Want to conditionally create vertices if there is an optional match on a path:

```
with [
 {customer: 0001, created: 1474434591, version: "1.0.0"},
 {customer: 0001, created: 1474434500, version: "1.0.0"},
 {customer: 0003, created: 1474445743, version: "1.1.0"}
] as lines 
unwind lines as line
/// customers above already exist
MATCH (c:Customer {id: line.customer})
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS]->(co:Configuration) WHERE co.created >= line.created
WITH CASE WHEN co IS NULL THEN
  [1]
END as createInventory,
CASE WHEN co IS NOT NULL THEN 
  [count(co)]
END as throwError, c, line
FOREACH (x in createInventory |
  CREATE (n:Configuration {
   created: line.created,
   version: line.version
  })
  CREATE UNIQUE (c)-[:HAS]->(n)
)
FOREACH (x in throwError |
  CREATE (e:Error:Inventory { message: "Configuration " + line.created + " >= existing (" + x + ")" })
);
```

The expectation is that only 2 `Configuration` vertices would be created and associated with a `Customer`.  Instead, all 3 `Configuration` instances are created. The write statements (i.e. create) are within the same transaction so I assume that individual writes aren't reflected when looping through the `OPTIONAL MATCH`.  In this example, a row is a `Configuration` and I don't want to create new ones tied to the same `Customer` if it's **created** property is older than an existing.  Thus the predicate in the `OPTIONAL MATCH`.

Any way to conditionally create and take into account writes within the same transaction (or Cypher statement)?

Comment: You say you "don't want to create new ones tied to the same Customer if it's created property is older than an existing", but your  `co.created >= line.created` test seems to only allow the ones you say you don't want. Is there an error somewhere, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @cybersam The **created** property in the second element in the lines array is "older" than the first. The first line creates the **HAS** relationship between the customer and the configuration vertices. The optional match should return null on the second line. That was my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher never "loops" back up to prior clauses.

You might get what you expected by inserting this clause right after your `UNWIND` clause:

```
WITH
  line.customer AS lc,
  REDUCE(s = NULL, x IN COLLECT(line) | CASE WHEN s IS NULL OR x.created > s.created THEN x ELSE s END) AS line
```

This `WITH` clause gets, per distinct `line.customer` value, the `line` having the highest `created` value, dropping any other lines. (The reason this is "per customer" is because of the use of the [`COLLECT` aggregation function within that WITH clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-with)).

*By the way, it makes no sense for your query to use `CREATE UNIQUE` instead of `CREATE`, since the `n` node that you created just before is brand new and therefore the specified pattern could not have existed before.*

Comment: @cypersam, Implicit group-by with **WITH** when the last part of the result set is an aggregation.  Cool.  Your solution plays nice even with LOAD.