# Cypher query with chaining does not propagate

Tags: cypher, amazon-neptune, opencypher

In the following cypher query, whenever the $dlt parameter is false, the query never continues beyond the DETACH DELETE statement:

```
MATCH (person:Person {id: $id})
SET person.matched = (CASE person.secret WHEN $secret THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
WITH person WHERE person.matched = 1 AND $dlt = true
MATCH (person)<-[:UsedBy]-(dev:Device)
DETACH DELETE dev
WITH person WHERE person.matched = 1
MERGE (person)<-[r:UsedBy {assignedDate: dateTime()}]-(device:Device {id: 'efgh', firebaseToken: 'jjjj8888'})
WITH person, person.matched as matched
REMOVE person.matched
RETURN
CASE matched
WHEN 0 
THEN null
ELSE person END AS Person
```

The idea is that all Device nodes (and connecting edges) needs to be removed only when the $dlt is true. However, regardless of $dlt (and this is what is not happening) - the subsequent parts must continue (adding a new Device node with a connecting edge, deleting the temporary matched property from person and returning based on matched value).

*Btw, I'm running this query from a Jupyter Notebook against an AWS Neptune DB, with the %%oc magic command on top.
As this is just for testing, I am not really using parameters (e.g. $dlt) in the Jupyter Notebook, but rather hard-coding some values.*

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Are you using the `%%oc` magic to submit the query or some other way? If using `%%oc` then parameters need to be substituted using the `${x}` syntax. If you are passing the parameters in and submitting the query some other way, can you please update the question to show that part as well? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin. Updated the question. Queries are running great until I have some conditional flow issues (as explained in the question above)

Comment: If `$dlt` is `false` the query is going to end, as nothing will flow out from the `WITH` clause as `false` is never equal to `true`. Perhaps try re-ordering the query to do the mandatory parts first and then do any optional parts.

Comment: I see. Hmmm. I am facing flow issues in many queries. What's the proper way to implement conditional blocks, such as If X then do y but if a then do b, and always flow on to the last RETURN statement?

Comment: Hopefully the suggestions in the two answers below will give you some template queries to build from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

### openCypher/Neptune answer

Since [openCypher](http://opencypher.org/) is a limited version of Cypher, the simplest thing would be to split this particular query in two: do the optional deletion in one query and then the optional merge in another. If the 2 queries should be done together atomically, you can use a [Mutation Bolt transaction query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-transactions.html#access-graph-opencypher-transactions-wr), and that transaction code can return the appropriate value after it performs both individual queries.

Or you can explore clever ways to use `OPTIONAL MATCH`, `FOREACH`, and so forth. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613736/effects-of-writing-clause-not-visible) and its answer may be instructive.

### Cypher answer

You can use [CALL subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) to do conditional processing that does not abort the rest of the query.

For example, the following version of your query might work for you. It uses "unit subqueries". A unit subquery does not return anything and does not affect the rows being processed by the enclosing query.

Note that I also simplified your query by not bothering to set and then remove the temporary `matched` property on each `Person`, which is wasteful of time and resources. Also, there was no reason to treat booleans as integers.

```
MATCH (person:Person {id: $id})
WITH person, (person.secret = $secret) AS matched
CALL {
  WITH person, matched
  WITH person, matched
  WHERE matched AND $dlt
  MATCH (person)<-[:UsedBy]-(dev:Device)
  DETACH DELETE dev
}
CALL {
  WITH person, matched
  WITH person, matched
  WHERE matched
  MERGE (person)<-[r:UsedBy {assignedDate: dateTime()}]-(device:Device {id: 'efgh', firebaseToken: 'jjjj8888'})
}
RETURN (CASE WHEN matched THEN null ELSE person END) AS Person
```

#### If/Else Processing

As a bonus, the following is an simple example of how to use [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union) to do "if/else" processing that does not abort the rest of the enclosing query. In this example, the subquery is not a "unit subquery" and returns a `type` variable that is visible to the enclosing query.

```
UNWIND [1,2,3,4,5] AS x
CALL {
    WITH x
    WITH x
    WHERE x % 2 = 0
    RETURN 'even' AS type
  UNION
    WITH x
    WITH x
    WHERE x % 2 <> 0
    RETURN 'odd' AS type
}
WITH x, type, x^2 AS squared //arbitrary post-subquery processing
RETURN x, type, squared
ORDER BY x
```

Comment: Amazon Neptune does not currently support CALL subqueries (which are not part of the openCypher spec AFAIK) which is why I was trying to stay within those boundaries in the discussions above.

Comment: Ah. I would suggest that you use "opencypher" instead of "Cypher" in your question to make it super clear. But at least you can improve your query a bit. In your use case there is no need to set and remove temporary properties, and booleans should just be used as-is. These suggestions will not solve your main problem, though. Unfortunately, `opencyper` is not very powerful at this point, and will probably always lag behind Cypher.

Comment: See my updated answer for a suggested solution to this use case.

Comment: Many thanks @cybersam. btw. ForEach is also not supported by openquery, and I don't want to use bolt just for this issue. Yes, atomicity is important. I just duplicated and have two versions of the query, conditionally calling one or the other from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussions and some thinking about how OPTIONAL MATCH can help along with some query re-ordering, here is a version that should work on Neptune. In this case, if there is an OPTIONAL MATCH  result and `$dlt` is TRUE, the `dev` will get deleted. If there is no match (including if `$dlt` is FALSE) then `dev` should be `null` and therefore nothing will get deleted. The rest of the query after the DELETE line should continue to the end either way.

```
MATCH (person:Person {id: $id})
SET person.matched = (CASE person.secret WHEN $secret THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
WITH person WHERE person.matched = 1
OPTIONAL MATCH (person)<-[:UsedBy]-(dev:Device)
WHERE $dlt = true
DETACH DELETE dev
WITH person WHERE person.matched = 1
MERGE (person)<-[r:UsedBy {assignedDate: dateTime()}]-(device:Device {id: 'efgh', firebaseToken: 'jjjj8888'})
WITH person, person.matched as matched
REMOVE person.matched
RETURN
CASE matched
WHEN 0 
THEN null
ELSE person END AS Person
```

Comment: Thank you @kelvin. I dont see how this will work, as the optional query may return a valid path, and the following WHERE may be false and break the flow beyond that point. Anyway, I ended up duplicating the query and conditionally call one or the other from the app.